# App/task icons in Visual Studio Team Explorer Project are missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

On one of my PCs I seem to have removed the handy app and task icons from the 'project' area of the Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2013.

Here's what I see on most of my machines and what I hope and expect to see:

[image: screenshot]

But here's the same window on my laptop which is now missing those icons as you can see:

[image: screenshot]

I have no idea what I did to loose those icons, nor how to add them back - I cannot find it in the settings anywhere. Does anyone know how to restore the app / task icons to the project area in Visual Studio's Team Explorer window?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running Visual Studio with this command-line switch:

`devenv.exe /setup`